Find if an array of strings can be chained to form a circle
We have n words.
We want to see if we can write n characters around a table in such a way that we can obtain all the words by starting from one of these n characters and moving clockwise.
Note that if a word is repeated m times, it must appear exactly m times in the circle.
For example:
// Number of words - Number of letters in each word
3 3
abc
bca
cab

Result:
abc
Second example:
4 2
aa
ab
ba
bb

Result:
aabb
We expect to find a string of length n that can be rotated clockwise from one of its characters to obtain all the words.

It's an interesting problem. I'm just not sure what part of the problem you're asking for help with?  Just the algorithm?  The greedy brute force algorithm is not hard to imagine.  Try all words as the next word.  If you get a conflict, then back up and try the next word.

A brute force approach:


function findWord(words){
  words = words.match(/\S+/g);
  let r = words[0];
  for(let i=1;i<words.length;i++){
    const word = words[i];
    if((r + r).includes(word)) continue;
    for(const c of [...word].reverse()){
      while(!r.endsWith(word)) r += c;
    }
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(findWord('aa ab ba bb'));
console.log(findWord('abc bca cab'));



